# Display an Ajax success message

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, submit

I am trying to make an ajax call and then to display a success message.
I have a php form which posts some data.
Here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#valuesubmit').click(function(event) {
        var formData = new FormData($('form#devAdd')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/addDevice.php',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $('#settingsMessage').html(response["msg"]);
            }
        });
   });
});
</script>
```

Then there is a php file which makes the appropriate checks before submit.

This file generates a message

```
if(trim($Name) == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Name, is required.'));
} else if(trim($DevID) == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'State, is required'));
} else if(trim($IconID) == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Town, is required'));
}
```

So the last part should show this msg inside the settingsMessage DIV.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error in console?. Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#valuesubmit').click(function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData($('form#devAdd')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/addDevice.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            $('#settingsMessage').html(response.msg);
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

you had empty: `success: function(response){`

Comment: you have an html element with the id `settingsMessage`?. Check the console. make a `console.log(response);` before the `$('#settingsMessage').html(response.msg);` But first, check if the PHP is returning the answer you want (with postman or change from POST to GET and you set parameters on URL). And edit the question with the HTML please